# How do I use kubectl properly to find out if all deployments with specific label completed?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I need to find out if all deployments having label=a is in READY state? Example is below. I need to return true or false based on wether all deployments are in READY or NOT ready? I can parse text but I think there might be a more clever way with just kubectl and json path or something

```
PS C:\Users\artis> kubectl get deployment -n prod -l role=b
NAME           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
apollo-api-b   0/3     3            0           107s
esb-api-b      0/3     3            0           11m
frontend-b     3/3     3            3           11m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kubectl get deploy -l foo=bar -o json 
| jq -r '[.items[]|select(.status.readyReplicas!=.status.replicas)]|length'
```

if != 0 then something still not ready
you can also do ie. `readyReplicas > 0` if one is enough for your needs regardless of how many should be ready in the desired state

Answer (score 1):

Add `-o yaml` to see the YAML objects for each, which you can then use to build a `-o jsonpath` like `-o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.status.conditions[?(@.type == "Available")].status}{"\n"}{end}'`. You can't do logic operations in JSONPath so you'll need to filter externally like `| grep  False` or something.